# Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output

Tags: java-ee, soap, java-8, maven

Cuando trato de correrlo con la opción "Maven build..." me aparece este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output (org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.5:wsgen:generate-wsdl:process-classes)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Invocation of com.sun.tools.ws.wscompile.WsgenTool failed - check output
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.exec(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:485)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.processSei(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractWsGenMojo.executeJaxws(AbstractWsGenMojo.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.MainWsGenMojo.executeJaxws(MainWsGenMojo.java:118)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxws.AbstractJaxwsMojo.execute(AbstractJaxwsMojo.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.cibertec.soap</groupId>
  <artifactId>api-soap</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <!-- LIBRERIAS PARA SOAP CON MAVEN -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet provided by tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
            <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/policy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.gmbal/gmbal-api-only -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-b003</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.ha/ha-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
            <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- HERRAMIENTA PARA GENERAR LOS ARCHIVOS SOAP -->
        <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsgen</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sei>edu.cibertec.soap.FifaImpl</sei>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <resourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl</resourceDestDir>
                            <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Estoy que trabajo con java 1.8 ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?